# Передача параметров в функцию

Tags: javascript, функции, chrome-extension

Пытаюсь передать два параметра функции, но первый передаётся неудачно, а второй нормально. Как правильно реализовать? Вот сама функция:

```
function setValue(Variable,Value) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({Variable: Value});
}
```

Пытаюсь её вызвать вот так: `setValue('test', 'testvalue');`,
но первый параметр как бы передаётся (проверял с помощью `alert(Variable)`), но не хочет "применяться" в коде .
К примеру вот так работает:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({test: "testvalue"});
```

И вот так работает (я передавать буду только 1 параметр,а нужно 2) :

```
function setValue(Value) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"test": Value});
}
```

успешно срабатывает: `setValue("testvalue");`

Пробовал что-то типа такого:

```
function setValue(Variable,Value) {
    var Variable = String(Variable);
    chrome.storage.sync.set({Variable: Value});
}
```

но не выходит.

Как правильно это сделать ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы передаете в функцию `chrome.storage.sync.set` Object, у которого есть поле, с *названием* `'Variable'`, т.е. Ваше значение лежит не в ключе `"test"`, а в ключе `"Variable"`.

Чтобы сохранить так, как вы хотите, достаточно создать объект и присвоить значение вычисленному свойству:

```
function setValue(Variable,Value) {
    var tmp = {};
    tmp[Variable] = Value; //в данном случае, имя ключа будет вычислено
    chrome.storage.sync.set(tmp);
}

//либо (может отвалиться в относительно "старых" браузерах)
function setValue(Variable,Value) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({[Variable]: Value});
}
```

Подробнее можно почитать, например на http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/intro

P.S. в js не принято обозначать переменные с большой буквы

Comment: справка по [новой нотации в ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: Здравствуйте,спасибо за ответ,помогло . А как быть тут ?
function getValue(variable, defaultvalue) {
chrome.storage.sync.get({
    variable: defaultvalue,
  }, function(items) { 
    if (items.variable) {
  return items.variable;
  }});
}